# Why need gc and can we write language without this but memory safety?

Tags: garbage-collection

I'm wondering if there are algorithms that can find the exact lifetime of an object and when it can be deleted. If there are no such algorithms, then why? Please, provide references to articles where I can find more information.

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting

Comment: No, I want algorithm that works in compile time.

Comment: @Andru rust is what you want to check.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to automatic storage and automatic pointers, C++ provides you with exactly that. If, however, you are going to use heap allocations without automatic pointers, it will be precisely, because the objects’ lifetimes will be nontrivial and unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of an object lifetime (during compile-time or run-time) isn't effective enough to be usable without a (tracing) garbage collector. [Escape-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) is a known method to find the scope of certain object pointers and thus automatically insert a free statement once the object is no longer used. In Java for example this is done by the [HotSpot VM's JIT compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis), since there are no bytecode instructions for freeing memory it can't be done compile-time (without using non-standard bytecode instructions), I think this is also the same for Javascript.

Escape analysis and other such algorithms are useful for reducing the GC pressure, however they can't be used only by themself. Imagine (an optimal scenario) that escape analysis can detect 40% of the allocations in a program, without GC 60% of the allocations will not be reclaimed and thus the program will eventually run out of memory. As for finding the lifetime (scope) of all objects this isn't possible, a simple (Java) example would be the following:

```
public Object getFriendIfOnline(String name) {
   Object friend = Server.requestFriendObject(name);
   if(friend.isOnline()) {
     return friend;
   } else {
     return null;
   }
}
```

It's impossible to know compile-time whether the friend object will be returned (and remain alive) or discarded (and be unused). If you free the object regardless, it'll cause a premature free and break your program.

Doing heavy compile-time analysis for object lifetimes can be useful in some special cases like running high-level languages on embedded systems with low resources. Using an embedded VM with support for memory freeing in combination with such analysis can reduce GC pressure and increase CPU and memory efficiency. This [paper](http://suraj.lums.edu.pk/zartash/publications/2011-11-SenSys-OfflineGC.pdf) describes some compile-time Offline GC methods used in the context of low-resource embedded systems.